# Python: exec() fucntion not working in Flask

Tags: python

In my Flask application I want to execute code coming from a database. But the exec function seems not to work. To test it in one of my route I put the simple code:

```
x = 0
exec("x = 10", globals(), locals())
print(x)
```

There is no error but the value of x stays at 0. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

working fine, value changed to 10, see for yourself,
[image]

Update: I think it's happening because of a scop problem with your variable in Flask, so try this code:

```
x = 0
exec("global x", globals(), locals())
exec("x = 10", globals(), locals())
print(x)
```

Comment: That works in a simple program but not in my flask route

Comment: oh, I think it's a scop problem, try to use the globe keyword too, see the updated answer.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately same result, I still have x=0

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not failing to be executed, it's just not updating the local variables for your function (for example, try replacing the string being executed with a `print` statement instead of a variable assignment).

According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec:

> [...] modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns.

Hopefully someone else manages to explain why locals aren't shared between `exec` and the function scope when running inside a flask view, but if you need to do so one workaround could be:

```
_vars = {'x': 0}
exec("x = 10", _vars)
print(_vars['x'])
```